# Symfon2 Process is not starting with & - Ampersand

Tags: symfony, symfony-process

I have a symfony command to send emails. In the terminate listener, I run this command.

Below is the command I run,

```
php ../app/console insead:email:prepare <Base64 information> &
```

I passed **& (Ampersand)** sign to the command in order to spawn a new process on the shell.

The version of Symfony was **2.4** and it was working fine. Last week I updated the version to **2.7** and now it is **not working**.

It seems the command is not running in the shell. I am using Symfony Process.

```
$process = new Process($command, $this->rootDir);
$process->start();
```

I tried to get errorOutput, output and all of them return empty.

Did anybody face this kind of issue?

*(Note - My operating system is Windows 7 and I am running my application on top of WAMP)*

Comment: you may use the windows start command like `start app/console ...` or

Comment: Tried. But does not help. Anyway, thanks @johnSmith

Comment: I added `$process->setEnhanceWindowsCompatibility(false);` method call. And now it is working.